# Search a Keyword by KeywordMetadata

Tags: web8.5, brokerquery

I need to retrieve components that have linked a keyword which an specific metadata value.
As an entry we have the schema type, the field name and the keyword metadata value.

Is this possible with SDL Web 8.5 in a Java implementation? Is there any broker query that enables that with a good performance?

As an example. I want to retrieve Shop components that have the code IDSHOP: SEV-100 as metadata of the keyword.

**Component Shop XYZ**

- ShopName: Shop XYZ

**Category ShopName**

- Keyword Shop XYZ
- Key ID100
- KeywordMetadata IDSHOP: SEV-100

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to look for keywords with a certain metadata field in the broker. What you normally do, is search for components (sometimes pages) by passing in the ID or title of a keyword.

However, there may be a work-around. You can use the TaxonomyFactory to retrieve all keywords in a category, including their metadata fields. You can do this once, when the application starts, and then store the keywords in a hash table using this particular metadata field as the key. To find all Shop components which are tagged with a keyword which has this a given value in its IDSHOP metadata field, you would need to do the following:

- Find all the matching keywords in your hash table
- Add a KeywordCriteria or CategorizationCriteria for each keyword
- Combine all these criteria into an 'OrCriteria'
- Execute the query.